# Os.listdir NotADirectoryError Not working in MacOS - works in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, listdir

Not working in mac os, not sure why this isnt working, please help? Works fine in windows..Just brought a mac so, confused why this isn't working.

```
SUMMARIES_DIRECTORY_PATH = os.path.join(current_dir, "summaries")
NODECOUNTS_DIRECTORY_PATH = os.path.join(current_dir, "node_counts")
summaries_path_list = os.listdir(SUMMARIES_DIRECTORY_PATH)
nodecounts_path_list = os.listdir(NODECOUNTS_DIRECTORY_PATH)

coop_ratios_list = []
for summary_path in summaries_path_list:
    coop_ratio_list = []
    abs_summaries_path = os.path.join(SUMMARIES_DIRECTORY_PATH, summary_path)
    summaries = os.listdir(abs_summaries_path) //THIS LINE IS BREAKING// 
    for n in range(len(summaries)):
        abs_summary_path_generation = os.path.join(abs_summaries_path, "summary" + str(n) + ".csv")
        summary = pd.read_csv(abs_summary_path_generation)
        coop_ratio = np.mean(summary.Cooperation_rating)
        coop_ratio_list.append(coop_ratio)
    coop_ratios_list.append(coop_ratio_list)
```

traceback

```
summaries = os.listdir(abs_summaries_path)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:
```

Comment: Edit the question to show the full traceback as properly formatted text.

Comment: you can debug it by printing `abs_summaries_path `

Comment: summaries = os.listdir(abs_summaries_path)
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:

Answer (score 1):

It was because the being `.DS_Store` folder created by MacOS. It is a "hidden" (see [dotfile](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)). It was then added to the array..

This is how i solved it

```
if '.DS_Store' in summaries_path_list:
    summaries_path_list.remove('.DS_Store')
```